# Instalar entorno grafico en VPS Linux?

Tags: linux, hosting, vps

Buenas tardes!
Soy nuevo en administración de servidores `Linux`, tengo un `VPS Centros 6.9` que compre para probar y experimentar.
Tengo acceso `SSH` y tengo instalado el `WHM y CPANEL`.

Mi pregunta es si puedo instalarle un escritorio grafico, tipo `XFCE` que consume poco recursos.

Creo que si porque por consola puedo hacerlo, pero puedo mantener el `WHM` y `CPANEL` funcionando?

Y como me conectaria mediante escritorio remoto, puedo hacerlo por consola tambien?

Gracias!!

Comment: Si puedes hacerlo pero yo no lo recomendaría, ya que la interface sera lenta y tienes q hacer varios pasos para conectarte de manera grafica.

Comment: Gracias! Pirque seria lenta, lei por ahi que algunos escritorios ocupan solamente 256 o 512 de ram.

Comment: la lentitud no es por el consumo en el servidor, la lentitud se genera por lo que te tienes que conectar de manera remota a la interface gráfica que instales a diferencia de trabajar bajo la terminal.

Answer (score 2):

No hace falta instalar todo el entorno, y tampoco arrancar nada en el VPS. 
Solo tienes que hacer que las X se tunelicen via ssh y poner desde donde te conectas un servidor X.

En windows lo mas facil es instalar mobaxterm que lo tiene todo incluido, te conectas por ssh y ejecutas por ejemplo xterm y así compruebas que funciona. 
Si necesitas navegar desde el VPS, instalas el firefox, lo ejecutas en el ssh y se te abrirá en tu pantalla.

Answer (score 1):

Yo en lo personall no te lo recomiendo, lo ideal es usar el VPS mediante el bash por que el entorno grafico aunque no paresca si consume recursos que muy bien podrias utilizar en para procesos mas importantes ya que de eso se trata la administración de sistemas, aprovechar los recursos de la forma ideal y optimizar el sistema lo mas que se pueda.

Comment: Y en general si lo que quieres es vender web hosting puedes empezár con planes reseller ;)